# Running the same program in multiple cores of a processor using bash

Tags: bash, macos

I have a 8 core processor and I want to run a series of experiments on 3 of those cores, where I run a c++ binary against an instance. I was able to parallelize it using bash but I am unable to restrict the number of cores to 3.

Here is my bash script

```
run_graph_algo1(){
  ./../bin/graph_algo1_cpp "$1" > "${1}.algo1.log"
}
 

for file in *.txt
do
     run_graph_algo1 "$file" &
done

wait
echo "All Instances have finsihed running."
```

I am using MacOS if it matters, and I would rather not use any extra libraries. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU Parallel:

```
run_graph_algo1(){
  ./../bin/graph_algo1_cpp "$1" > "${1}.algo1.log"
}
export -f  run_graph_algo1

parallel -j3 run_graph_algo1 ::: *.txt

echo "All Instances have finsihed running."
```

GNU Parallel is built for exactly this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is a wrong solution. The below program will launch 3 separate tasks but it will wait for all the three to finish and then start the next three tasks. I want it to start the next task after any of the three tasks is finished so that at any point of time (except for towards the end, there are always three tasks running)

Upon further googling, I was able to find a working solution. But if anyone can give a more elegant solution, I would mark that as correct.

```
run_graph_algo1(){
  ./../bin/graph_algo1_cpp "$1" > "${1}.algo1.log"
}
 
N=3
#N = 4 just preserving this mistake 

for file in *.txt
do
     ((i=i%N)); ((i++==0)) && wait
     run_graph_algo1 "$file" &
done

wait
echo "All Instances have finsihed running."
```

Comment: @Kusalananda your re right. My bad and also it should be N=3 as I only want it to run on three cores. But This is not correct answer as I just noticed that  the next instance waits for all the three runs to finish and then start the next three runs.